# How to check if DataReader value is not null?

Tags: vb.net, oracle

I'm writing a VB.Net code that reads an Oracle Table through an SQL query.

The SQL query may return some null columns. I'm trying to check if these columns are null or not but I'm receiving the error **An exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in Oracle.DataAccess.dll but was not handled in user code. The column contains some Null Data**

Here is my code :

```vb
Dim Reader as OracleDataReader 
'Execute the query here...

Reader.Read()
If IsNothing(Reader.GetDateTime(0)) Then  'Error here !!
    'Do some staff 
end if
```

Does anyone have an idea on how to check if a column is null please ?

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Nothing` means an object has not been initialized, `DBNull` means the data is not defined/missing.  There are several ways to check:

```vb
' The VB Function
If IsDBNull(Reader.Item(0)) Then...
```

The `GetDateTime` method is problematic because you are asking it to convert a non value to DateTime.  `Item()` returns Object which can be tested easily *before* converting.

```vb
 ' System Type
 If System.DBNull.Value.Equals(...)
```

You can also the DbReader.  This only works with the ordinal index, not a column name:

```vb
If myReader.IsDbNull(index) Then
```

Based on that, you can put together functions either as Shared class members or reworked into Extensions to test for DBNull and return a default value:

```vb
Public Class SafeConvert
    Public Shared Function ToInt32(Value As Object) As Integer
        If DBNull.Value.Equals(Value) Then
            Return 0
        Else
            Return Convert.ToInt32(Value)
        End If
    End Function

    Public Shared Function ToInt64(Value As Object) As Int64
        If DBNull.Value.Equals(Value) Then
            Return 0
        Else
            Return Convert.ToInt64(Value)
        End If
    End Function

    ' etc
End Class
```

Usage:

```vb
myDate = SafeConvert.ToDateTime(Reader.Item(0))
```

For a DateTime converter, you'd have to decide what to return.  I prefer to do those individually.

Answer (score 3):

You need to check if the field is null *before* you convert the value to date.

```vb
If (Reader.IsDBNull(0)) Then
    'Null: Do not call GetDateTime
End If
```

```vb
If (Not Reader.IsDBNull(0)) Then
    'Not null: Retrieve the datetime.
    Dim dt As DateTime = Reader.GetDateTime(0)
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Generic function with extension, will make it easier.

```
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

<Extension()>
Public Module DataReaderExtensions
  Public Function GetValue(Of T)(ByVal drVar As Object) As T
    If drVar.Equals(DBNull.Value) Then
        ' Value is null, determine the return type for a default
        If GetType(T).Equals(GetType(String)) Then
            Return CType(CType("", Object), T)
        Else
            ' If it's anything else just return nothing
            Return CType(Nothing, T)
        End If
    Else
        ' Cast the value into the correct return type
        Return CType(drVar, T)
    End If
  End Function
End Module
```

And you can call it like

```
dr.Item("abc").GetValue(string)
dr.Item("def").GetValue(Nullable(of Date))
```