# Handling DBNull data

Tags: .net, vb.net, sql-server-2008, dbnull

I am assigning one datarow object the values of another datarow object. 
For example:

```
newAddress.AddrId     = frenchAddress.AddrId
newAddress.AddrLn1    = frenchAddress.AddrLn1
newAddress.AddrLn2    = frenchAddress.AddrLn2
newAddress.AddrLn3    = frenchAddress.AddrLn3
newAddress.AddrCityNm = frenchAddress.AddrCityNm
newAddress.CntryId    = frenchAddress.CntryId
newAddress.ProvId     = frenchAddress.ProvId
```

Some of the values in `frenchAddress` can be NULL so I end up getting an exception because I am assigning `newAddress` the value of `DBNull`. What is the best and cleanest way of handling `DBNull`? Is there anyway to just insert `NULL` where there is a `DBNull`?

Using VB.Net.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check if oracle table column is not null?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27765599/how-to-check-if-oracle-table-column-is-not-null)

Comment: What type is `frenchAddress`? Is it a typed DataRow?

Comment: @TimSchmelter yes it is.

Answer (score 1):

Since that is  a typed `DataRow`(so an auto-generated type with named properties) there are already methods for this purpose:

```
If frenchAddress.IsAddrCityNmNull Then
    newAddress.SetAddrCityNmNull()
Else
    newAddress.AddrCityNm = frenchAddress.AddrCityNm
End If
```

If it was not a typed but a standard `DataRow` you could use the `SetField` method that supports nullable types and also should handle this case:

```
newAddress.SetField("ColumnName", frenchAddress.Field(Of String)("ColumnName"))
```

Comment: Okay cool, I figured that would be the easiest way of doing that. Though is there a cleaner way of doing it? There's a lot of values being assigned in this particular function and if I could avoid over 10 `If` statements I'd prefer too.

Comment: @errorreplicating: that's the preferred way since it forces you to make decisions and to notice that this field can be null. On that way it prevents you from errors.

Comment: @errorreplicating: what type is that column? Have you tried my second approach that does use the standard `DataRow`, the strongly typed `DataRow` inherits from it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the IsDbNull function with the If statement for example:

```
newAddress.AddrLn1 = If (IsDbNull(frenchAddress.AddrLn1), String.Empty, frenchAddress.AddrLine1)
```

Answer (score 0):

This ended up being the solution I used, a little bit of a mixture between the two answer above. It seems to work ok:

```
newAddress.AddrLn1 = If(frenchAddress.IsAddrLn1Null = True, Nothing, frenchAddress.AddrLn1)
```