# Object initializing with db null check

Tags: vb.net, object, initialization, dbnull

I am trying to initialize an object with data from database return in a dataset as below:

[image: Example Dataset]

```
Class Pdf
    Public FileId As Integer
    Public AccountNumber As Integer
    Public DateSaved As DateTime
    Public FileName As String
    Public DateImported As DateTime
```

**Scenerio 1**
I can intialize the object like this:

```
Dim pdf = New Pdf With {.FileId = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i)("fileid"),
                        .AccountNumber = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i)("accountnumber"),
                        .DateSaved = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i)("datesaved"),
                        .FileName = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i)("filename"),
                        .DateImported = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i)("dateimported")
                        }
```

But this is not working, because column data can be null and I am not if how to do a db null check in this approach.

Then I have **scenerio 2**:

```
Dim pdf As New pdf
If Not IsDBNull(ds.Tables(0).Rows(i)("fileid")) Then
    PdfFileId = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i)("fileid")
Else
    PdfFileId = 0
End If

If Not IsDBNull(ds.Tables(0).Rows(i)("accountnumber")) Then
    pdf.AccountNumber = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i)("accountnumber")
Else
    pdf.AccountNumber = 0
End If

If Not IsDBNull(ds.Tables(0).Rows(i)("datesaved")) Then
    pdf.DateSaved = Format(ds.Tables(0).Rows(i)("datesaved"), "yyyy-MM-dd")
Else
    pdf.DateSaved = Nothing
End If

If Not IsDBNull(ds.Tables(0).Rows(i)("dateimported")) Then
    pdf.DateImported= Format(ds.Tables(0).Rows(i)("dateimported"), "yyyy-MM-dd")
Else
    pdf.DateImported= Nothing
End If
```

How can I do this to avoid doing so many `If` statements below. This way seems inefficient to me, can anyone suggest an better approach to initializing the object in scenario one or two?  If the question is unclear, please do let me know, I will try and explain.

Please note this is sample data.

Comment: have you tried just `ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Field(Of String)("FileName")` for example?

Comment: you could change those fieldsto  properties and add code in the setter to check for DBNull and respond or use a function/extension to return a default value when DBNull. Pretty bad idea to name your Class `OPbject` by the way - that could cause problems with the existing `System.Object`.  [Converter example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27765741/1070452)

Comment: @Ric no I have not, can you explain this a little?

Comment: @Plutonix it is sample data, hence the name. The actual class name is not Object :)

Comment: Have you tried nullable data type (an account number of 0 is not the same as null)? ex: Public AccountNumber As Integer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From reading `T Field<T>(this DataRow row, string columnName)`, I believe that there is a check for the DBNull.Value for both reference and value types, returning a default value if `DBNull.Value` is passed.

So you can use it instead of checking for `DBNull.Value` each time:

`.FileName = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Field(Of String)("FileName")`

> If the value of the specified DataColumn is null and T is a reference type or nullable type, the return type will be null. The Field method will not return Value.

[DataRowExtensions.Field](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360891(v=vs.110).aspx)

Since you cant use this then @TimSchmelter provided an answer which you could build upon:

`.FileId = If(row.IsNull("fileid"), 0, Convert.ToInt32(row("fileid"))`

Comment: Thanks ric, I wasnt aware of this extension method.

Comment: So you're not using 2.0 anymore?

Comment: Ah I see! Thats the best thing to do in situations like this. then you can use the `Field` method.

Comment: Yes definitley, one last thing... what is the significance of the 0 in this above statement If(row.IsNull("fileid"), 0, Convert.ToInt32(row("fileid"))?

Comment: basically, if the column value is null, the value returned by this statement will be 0, else it will be the actual column value, googe vb.net ternary operator

Comment: will that return 0 for non integer types? say string?

Comment: no, you would use this (returns empty string): If(row.IsNull("myField"), "", Convert.ToString(row("myField")), also @Tim's code has more examples.

Answer (score 0):

Its not inefficient but a lot of code, so maybe there is a more readable/maintainable approach.

The `If` operator is one, you can also use `DataRow.IsNull`:

```
For i As Int32 = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
    Dim row = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i)
    Dim pdf = New Pdf With {
        .FileId = If(row.IsNull("fileid"), 0, row.Field(Of Int32)("fileid")),
        .AccountNumber = If(row.IsNull("accountnumber"), 0, row.Field(Of Int32)("accountnumber")),
        .DateSaved = If(row.IsNull("datesaved"), Date.MinValue, row.Field(Of Date)("datesaved")),
        .FileName = If(row.IsNull("filename"), "", row.Field(Of String)("filename")),
        .DateImported = If(row.IsNull("dateimported"), Date.MinValue, row.Field(Of Date)("dateimported"))
    }
Next
```

(changed the name of your class from `Object` to `Pdf`)

You should also set `Option Strict` to `On`, then you need to code type safe but you gain compile time safety and avoid unwanted conversions.