# 'DBNULL error' while summing column on datatable using LINQ

Tags: vb.net, linq

I'm sure this is a pretty simple one, but I can't seem to find an answer anywhere...

i am trying to sum numeric values from a datatable using linq  but because there are also null values in column K i am getting a error:
`Cannot cast DBNull.Value to type 'System.Int32'. Please use a nullable type.` 
what is the proper syntax to overcome this error?

```
   Private table1 As DataTable
Private Function getIncome(ByVal acName As String, ByVal acTeam As String) As Integer
    Dim query = table1.AsEnumerable().Where(Function(x) x.Field(Of String)("G") = acName AndAlso x.Field(Of String)("F") = acTeam _
                    ).Sum(Function(x) x.Field(Of Integer)("K"))

    Dim total As Integer = query
    Return total
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

`Sum(Function(x) x.Field(Of Integer)("K"))`

Should be replaced with this:

`Sum(Function(x) x.Field(Of Integer?)("K"))`

The default value for `int` is returned (0) by using the `Field<T>()` method if `DBNull.Value` is returned so it is safe to use, see my other answer to this here

[Object initializing with db null check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32271839/object-initializing-with-db-null-check/32272040#32272040)