# "object cannot be cast from dbnull to other types" when select sql query runs

Tags: vb.net

I looking more about this "object cannot be cast from dbnull to other types" error. but I can't find possible answer to resolve problem.

```
Private Sub Button18_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button18.Click

            'query = "SELECT sum(fuel) as ttlfuel, sum(stationery) as ttlstationery, sum(salary) as ttlsalary, sum(v_part) as ttlvp, sum(other) as ttlother FROM mcs.expenses WHERE datee BETWEEN #" & dtpisf.Value.ToString & "# AND #" & dtpist.Value.ToString & ""
    Dim cmd = New MySqlCommand(query, con)
    Dim dr As MySqlDataReader
    Try
        con.Open()
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        While dr.Read()
            Me.txtfuel.Text = Convert.ToDecimal(dr("ttlfuel"))
            ' Me.txtstationary.Text = Convert.ToDecimal(dr("ttlstationery"))
            'Me.txtcollectorsalery.Text = Convert.ToDecimal(dr("ttlsalary"))
            'Me.txtvehiclepart.Text = Convert.ToDecimal(dr("ttlvp"))
            'Me.txtotherexpenses.Text = Convert.ToDecimal(dr("ttlother"))
        End While
        dr.Close()
        con.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
        Try
            If (con.State = ConnectionState.Open) Then
                con.Close()
            End If
        Catch ex2 As Exception
            MsgBox(ex2.Message)
        End Try
    End Try
```

In my program I had button and I coded it to get sum of each columns. And special thing is I want to filter these data between two dates by date time pickers. (dtpisf and dtpist).
My data table name is expenses. It's all data rows at least had 0 values.
Anybody can help ?

Comment: You have to check if those fields are DbNull (missing data) before you try to assign them to variables or controls.  [This may help](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27765741/1070452)

Comment: I suppose that your commented out query is not really commented out. Right?

Comment: Yuck.  Dont concat SQL use SQL parameters, and dont Tick dates, use `dtpisf.Value` provided it is a Date column.  There are also issues with "BETWEEN" but I cant find the link right now

Comment: In database I also use 'Date' as type of where date time picker find value in table.

Comment: Are you really getting the error when the query runs (as in the title)? Or later when you try to assign a `dr("xxxx")` item to something?

Comment: I mean when I clicked button that's the time query runs.

Comment: **on what line exaclty?**  Remove the Try/Catch so you can properly diagnose your code

Answer (score 0):

Leaving aside the other problems outlined in comments (eg - using a command and SQLParamemters instead of a dynamic string), I think your current problem is that you make an assumption that your fields:

(a) have a value and

(b) have the right TYPE of value stored to convert to the data type you want.

You could easily use an extension method to do the work of checking that (vb.net code below):

```
Public Module DataRowExtension
    <System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()>
    Function GetOrDefault(Of T)(row As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader, name As String, [default] As T) As T
        If IsDBNull(row(name)) Then
            Return [default]
        Else
            Return CType(row(name), T)
        End If
    End Function
End Module
```

Then, you can use this code to set values:

```
Me.txtfuel.Text = dr.GetOrDefault(of string)("ttlfuel", "")
```

or, for decimal:

```
decimal myValue = dr.GetOrDefault(of decimal)("ttlfuel", 0)
Me.txtfuel.Text = myValue.toString("#,##0.00")
```

In addition, I would **turn on option strict in your code**.  If you do, you'll catch problems like this one at compile time (instead of running into them at runtime).  And, if you can get @Plutonix to give you an answer... I would go with it.

Comment: Create a new file in your project, type "module" and add it there.  your extension will be picked up automagically.

Comment: sir !, I added it to new module, but "row As DataReader," line, there is a error. it show datareader red color underlined

Comment: ok.  will you try replacing with a specific type:  System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader (edited answer above).

Comment: sir that's okay. but one problem. I Add "Me.txtfuel.Text = dr.GetOrDefaultValue(of string)("ttlfuel", "")" code and there is error show at "GetOrDefaultValue"

Comment: Sir, I changed "GetOrDefault" but under "GetOrDefault" remain blue underline.
I make public module as you said. but I think I again call module to this form.