# .net ExtensionMethodeSQL Datareader GetValueOrDefault

Tags: .net, vb.net, extension-methods, datareader

A question about good practices, with ExtensionMethod !

i would like get values of datareader, but sometimes, i would like avoid null values, because VB.net and C# are differents, (default function doesn't exist in vb), i did this :

```
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Module ExtensionMethodeSQL

<Extension()>
Public Function GetValueOrDefault(Of T)(ByVal dtReader As SqlDataReader, ByVal index As Integer) As T

    If dtReader.IsDBNull(index) = True Then
        If GetType(T).IsValueType = True Then
            Dim defaultValue As T = Nothing
            Return defaultValue
        Else
            Return Nothing
        End If
    Else
        Return CType(dtReader.GetValue(index), T)
    End If

End Function

<Extension()>
Public Function GetValueOrDefault(Of T)(ByVal aString As SqlDataReader, ByVal fieldName As String) As T
    Return aString.GetValueOrDefault(Of T)(aString.GetOrdinal(fieldName))
End Function
End Module
```

Is that good ? something to make it better?

Not sure for using CType, is trycast better for ValueType ?

Thx

Comment: `default function doesn't exist in vb)`  the default *indexer* is called `Item` in vb.  another way to do that: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27765741

Comment: It is better to use simple function or should i use methode Extension ?

Comment: You can make them extensions if you want.  Rather than `SqlDataReader` you might want to use `DbDataReader` unless you only ever use one SQLSvr.  personally, I dont think overloads makes it more readable/controllable